# Where can I get MicrosoftAjax.js

Tags: asp.net-ajax

My website has to run behind a reverse proxy in production. This causes a problem with the path to the axd files, as others have [seen](http://forums.asp.net/p/1244750/2656981.aspx). The solution is to include the source js files directly in your application instead of getting them generated from the AjaxControlToolkit.dll. This works well for most of the files. But I can't find MicrosoftAjax.js on my machine. Where can I get this file? Specifically, where can I get the 3.5 version of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get to it by using reflector to open up System.Web.Extensions.dll. Look in the resources section for the js files. Right click on the file and choose 'Save As'.