# Ajax Client-side framework Error When Running HTML code

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a aspx page that uses ajax modal popup extender. I run the project successfully from Visual Studio, it works correctly with IE and Firefox as default browsers.

Now I took the html code and created an html file and put in the proper location. When I open the html file by double clicking on it, it is saying script error like “**ASP.Net Ajax Client-side framework failed to load**”. Why is it happening when I create an HTML file and open it; and not happening when I run the aspx page from Visual Studio. How to overcome it? What should be the best method to take care this in **deployment to production**?

---

Note: I have not entered any entries in the **Web.Config** related to Ajax. We are not using any update panel. We have used ToolkitScriptManager in the aspx page.
Note: There is one more message after this – **‘Sys’ is undefined**.

---

Answer (score 1):

Are the path of microsoft AJAX related JS files still valid/pointing to correct folder after you copy HTML to a location?

Comment: I don't see ajax related scripts in my Scripts folder. But it works fine when I run from Visual Studio. Where do I see those files?

Comment: See --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773903/where-can-i-get-microsoftajax-js